# Media transfer peer to peer

Tags: streaming, media, pjsip

Assertion failed: (pool && src), function pjmedia_codec_param_clone, file ../src/pjmedia/codec.c, line 53.
Abort trap: 6

How to fix this problem, it comes when I am trying to run streamutil.c file from pjsip-apps

Comment: Please share with us more of your code and some context

Comment: @MartinPrikryl this comes when i run the code and the code u can find here http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk/pjsip-apps/src/samples/streamutil.c
18:07:30.741 os_core_unix.c !pjlib 2.1 for POSIX initialized
18:07:30.765       pa_dev.c  PortAudio sound library initialized, status=0
18:07:30.765       pa_dev.c  PortAudio host api count=1
18:07:30.765       pa_dev.c  Sound device count=2
18:07:30.765          pjlib  select() I/O Queue created (0x7f8182819028)
Assertion failed: (pool && src), function pjmedia_codec_param_clone, file ../src/pjmedia/codec.c, line 53.
Abort trap: 6